# mPDF - footer is working only on last page

Tags: php, footer, mpdf

I saw the other similar questions here, but I couldn't resolve my problem.
My problem is: the header is working normally in all pages, but the footer is showing only on last page.

```
<?
$mpdf = new mPDF(   '',    // mode - default ''
                '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
                0,     // font size - default 0
                '',    // default font family
                15,    // margin_left
                15,    // margin right
                58,     // margin top
                60,    // margin bottom
                6,     // margin header
                0,     // margin footer
                'L' );  // L - landscape, P - portrait
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$cabecalho = '<div>header</div>'; 
$paragrafo = '<div>body</div>'; 
$stylesheet = "table{
                  width: 100%;
                  text-align:center;
                  border: 2px solid black;
               }
";

$footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">{PAGENO}</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabecalho);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($paragrafo);

$mpdf->SetFooter($footer);

$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

What's the problem with footer here?

Comment: try this `SetHTMLFooter()` instead of `SetFooter()`

Comment: @severinolorillajr i have tried too, it happens the same problem

Comment: I edited the ask, and put the start of my code

Comment: have you checked the documentation lately?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try to put `setFooter()` before `WriteHTML()`

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabecalho);
$mpdf->SetFooter($footer);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($paragrafo);
$mpdf->AddPage('','','','b','off');
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: This breaks `setAutoBottomMargin => 'stretch'` & defined `margin_bottom` :/

Comment: Ah, nevermind! After hours of struggling I finally got mine working! `SetHTMLFooter` needs to be set inbetween stylesheets and html! Then it appears on every page, and custom bottom margins works.

Answer (score 4):

use `SetHTMLFooter()` and add it before `WriteHTML()` right after `SetHTMLHeader()`

hope that will resolve the footer issue

**Other Info:**

> void SetHTMLFooter(String $html, string $side)
>
> void SetFooter( $footer, $side)

SetFooter is already deprecated but will still work..

```
$footer = array(
    'L' => array {
        'content' => '',
        'font-size' => 10,
        'font-style' => 'B',
        'font-family' => '',
        'color' => '#000000'
    },
    'C' => array {
        'content' => '',
        'font-size' => 10,
        'font-style' => 'B',
        'font-family' => '',
        'color' => '#000000'
    },
    'R' => array {
        'content' => '',
        'font-size' => 10,
        'font-style' => 'B',
        'font-family' => '',
        'color' => '#000000'
    },
    'line' => 1
);
```

$side can be `O` for Odd pages, `E` for Even pages or blank for all pages.

For the documentation check this link

http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/mpdfmanual.pdf

Comment: what is doing this footer array? i didn't understand

Comment: can you try this: use `SetHTMLFooter()` and add it before `WriteHTML()` hope that will resolve the footer issue.. @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo